# Strange messages in OC4J log

Tags: struts-1, oc4j

I was debugging a simple Struts 1 application and suddenly I spotted this on the log.

[image: oc4j log]

It's a Struts 1 application running on an embedded OC4J that is included in JDeveloper 9.0.5.2

Apparently tfd.com is another domain for thefreedictionary.com but my application doesn't use any external apis and then there's also the message about OpenGL.

Any idea about what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118193/strange-message-in-terminal-when-visiting-a-website),
the source of that 'permission to use the keyboard' message could be from Firefox running in the background.

According to [this article](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2794913),
the OpenGL messages could also be from Firefox.

Comment: It makes sense: Firefox is my default browser and when I run/debug an application it's launched by JDeveloper. Also thefreedictionary is my start page so that explains the url. I launched Firefox with -console and -jsconsole to see if the same errors where thrown but I had no luck, I guess that was a very specific case.